# Find a header, copy a certain range, find a marker and paste it there

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code which copies a certain range from Sheet1, searches in Sheet4 for a text called "Marker 1" and pastes the copied range from Sheet1 in Sheet4 beginning in the cell of "Marker 1".

```
Sub FindCopyPasteV1()

    Dim FindM1 As Range
    Dim CopyM1 As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:DD")

        Set CopyM1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E6:E32")

    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A:DD")

        Set FindM1 = .Find(What:="Marker 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        CopyM1.Copy FindM1

    End With

End Sub
```

Now I want to change the code so that I can use a Range Object (FindH1) for the selection of the cells which I want to copy from Sheet1.

```
Sub FindCopyPasteV2()

    Dim FindH1 As Range
    Dim FindM1 As Range
    Dim CopyM1 As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:DD")

        Set FindH1 = .Find(What:="Header 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        Set CopyM1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("FindH1.E32") 'This doesn't work.

         'Instead of Set CopyM1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E6:E32")

    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A:DD")

        Set FindM1 = .Find(What:="Marker 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        CopyM1.Copy FindM1

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use Resize to reference a range beginning at the found cell: `Set CopyM1 = FindH1.Resize(howManyRows, howManyCols)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Resize to reference a range beginning at the found cell:

```
Set CopyM1 = FindH1.Resize(howManyRows, howManyCols)
```